# Invoking maven plugin as a part of build lifecycle

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I’m new to maven. I’m trying to integrate a plugin into my build so that it would execute automatically as part of phase execution.

Say I want to plug into clean lifecycle phase.

The mojo I’m using was annotated specifying that it should be injected into clean phase:

```
/**
* 
 * @goal clean
 * @phase clean
 * @requiresProject
 */

public class CleanMojo extends AbstractSCAMojo {
```

This mojo was installed following instructions in [Using Plugin Tools Java5 Annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html).
I added plugin to my pom.xml:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>myclean.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>myclean-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <logfile>C:/temp/clean.log</logfile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In my understanding having lifecycle binding in Mojo java code eliminates the need to provide executions in build-plugins-plugin. Is that correct?

I was expecting that after invoking *mvn clean* configured above *myclean.plugin:myclean-maven-plugin* will be executed as part of the clean goal, but nothing happens besides regular maven clean procedure.

When pom is changed to specify `executions` *myclean.plugin:myclean-maven-plugin* is invoked so I’m certain mojo code doesn’t contain blocking errors – this is just a question of configuration.

There is probably something more I need to specify to make plugin executed automatically (i.e. without specifying `executions`), but what?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? I have my doubts that you need to write a plugin before you have checked if there are already plugins which solve your problem.

Comment: I'd like to achive _understanding_.

Comment: It is year 2021 and I want my plugin to do cleaning up when `mvn clean` is executed. However, same as you, I have found out it does not work when I just specify the `CLEAN` phase. Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html), you should be adding the following annotation before the class definition:

```
@Mojo(name = "clean", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.clean)
```

`@goal` and `@phase` are for javadocs.

Comment: This is probably slightly more complicated
With
`@Mojo(name = "clean", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.CLEAN)`
plugin wont build
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.4:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project mymojo: Error extracting plugin descriptor: 'Goal: clean already exists in the plugin descriptor for prefix: mymojo
If I give a diffent name to goal like
`@Mojo(name = "myclean", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.CLEAN)` 
everything builds fine but my mojo doesn't get invoked automatically.